# What's wrong with this javascript & html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this short html and javascript code. You can access the code at http://jsfiddle.net/a4Mz5/8/, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am looking for value to be populated on click of submit.

```
<html>
<head> Simple page </head>
<body>    
    <form id="enrollment">
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="updateCost();">

        value = <input type="text" name="cost">
    </form>    

<script>
function updateCost(){
    document.enrollment.cost.value = formatCurrency(0.9946153813);
}
function formatCurrency(num) {
    if(isNaN(num)) return "$0.00";
    // ACCOUNTING RULES: ROUND DOWN IF LAST DIGIT IS 5 AND SECOND TO LAST DIGIT IS EVEN
    num = new String(parseFloat(num).toFixed(3));
    if(num.charAt(num.length-1) == '5' && parseInt(num.charAt(num.length-2)) % 2 == 0) {
    num = num.substring(0,num.length-1);
    }   
    var cents = Math.abs(Math.round((num * 100) % 100));
    if(cents < 10) {
        cents = "0" + cents;
    }    
    var n = ""; var count = 0; var neg = num < 0;
    num = Math.floor(Math.abs(num)).toString();
    for(var i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(count > 0 && count % 3 == 0) n = "," + n;
        n = num.charAt(i) + n;
        count++;
    }    
    return (neg ? "-" : "") + ("$" + n + "." + cents);
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Under "Choose Framework", pick "no wrap (head)" instead of "onLoad".
2. Change `<form id="enrollment">` to `<form name="enrollment">`

Answer (score 1):

I can't make it work in the jsFiddle. It keeps showing an error of `ReferenceError: updateCost is not defined`.

[EDIT] The below answer works in the jsFiddle if you change `onLoad` to `no wrap (head)`

I brought all the code to an HTML file on my computer, placing the javascript in the head, and it worked once I changed

```
document.enrollment.cost.value = 1221;
```

to

```
document.forms.enrollment.cost.value = 1221;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <html>
    <head> 
    <title>Simple page</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
         function updateCost(){
            document.getElementsByName('cost')[0].value = 1221;
         }
     </script> 
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form id="enrollment">
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="updateCost();">

            value = <input type="text" name="cost">
        </form>
```